# What task can "duplicate" / "copy" certain rows in Azure Data Flow?

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I need to "duplicate" / "copy" certain rows in my dataset of a CSV file in an Azure Data Flow.

Every row that starts with 300 I need to "copy" / "duplicate" in order to create a row 350.

For example if my input is:

100 a

200 b

300 c

100 d

200 e

300 f

Then I would like my output to be:

100 a

200 b

300 c

350 c

100 d

200 e

300 f

350 f

is this possible within a Data Flow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a new branch then filter this stream to get rows which starts with '300'.

Then use `DerivedColumn` to change '300' to '350'.

Finally, add a union to combine your source stream and DerivedColumn stream. You can sort them if you need.

Below is the screenshot of my test.

[image]

Details:

My test data
[image]

Setting of Filter
[image]

Setting of DerivedColumn
[image]

Setting of Union
[image]

Setting of Sort
[image]

Data preview of Sort
[image]

Comment: thank you so much.  I will give this a try today, but it looks great!